# Why is INSTALLED_APPS missing from django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am studying the content here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

The above page suggests I clone a repo:

```
git clone git@github.com:tomchristie/django-rest-framework.git
```

So I did that; it says I should add an entry to `INSTALLED_APPS` in project `settings.py`, I did that. Next, I looked at project settings.py in DRF sources on github and I see no evidence of `INSTALLED_APPS` [there](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py).

Question:

why is INSTALLED_APPS missing from DRF source code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation was a bit unclear. You are supposed to add the `rest_framework` line to the `settings.py` file in *your* application.

Cloning the repository is just an alternative to pip for installing it locally.

- Create a new django project with `django-admin startproject mysite`
- Install rest framework with `pip install djangorestframework`
- Edit `mysite/mysite/settings.py` and add `rest_framework` to the installed apps.

You don't have to worry about what's going on inside django-rest-framework

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Edit mysite/mysite/settings.py and add rest_framework to the installed apps." step?  I'm in my `settings.py` document and it's a long document with a lot of places to add this.

Comment: locate  INSTALLED_APPS variable and append rest_framework to the list. @mrmicrowaveoven